# How to make str_detect or str_extract work?

Tags: regex, stringr

Below is my code:

```
example <- c("aaaa","aaab","abab","abba","baaa","baba","bbba","bbbb")
example <- as.data.frame(example)

example1 <- c("zzzz","zzzy","zyzy","zyyz","yzzz","yzyz","yyyz","yyyy")
example1 <- as.data.frame(example1)

df <- cbind(example, example1)

library(stringr)
detect<- str_detect(df,"aaaa")
```

And yet this does not manage to detect the "aaaa" in one cell.

Instead, it shows FALSE for every row.

Comment: `str_detect(df$example,"aaaa")` yields TRUE for the first row. What exactly do you need?

Comment: My results show FALSE for every row

Comment: Because you are not checking a column, you pass the whole dataframe which is wrong. You must get "*Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing*" warning

Comment: It is the same as using `str_detect(colnames(df),"aaaa")`. If you rename `example` to `eaaaaxample`, you will get  match, since you are just searching in the column names only

Answer (score 0):

`str_detect(df,"aaaa")` performs a search on the column names, it is the same as using `str_detect(colnames(df),"aaaa")`. Since your `example` and `example1` do not contain four `a`s, you get two `FALSE`. If you rename `example` to `eaaaaxample`, you will get a match.

However, you must be probably searching for a match in the `example` column:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(df$example,"aaaa")
# => [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/KMmzSQ)